# Should I add "do" after "As they were supposed to" in this example?

Tags: auxiliary

Should I add "do" after "As they were supposed to" in this example?

> When everybody left the room, Mary and Ann, at last, could talk as two real friends are supposed to
> **(do?)**.

Comment: Strictly speaking, ***do*** is just a "generic alternative" to avoid repeating the specific *actual* verb here - *[they] could talk as two real friends are supposed to **talk***. But having any verb there at all is entirely optional, and in practice native speakers usually don't bother with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the previous phrases are quite long, 'do' isn't usually used (based on personal experience). For example:

This sounds natural:

> They should be working by now, as they are supposed to.

This also sounds natural:

> They should be working on the project by now, as they are supposed to do.

So it doesn't really matter that much.

Here's also one more example:

> What am I supposed to do?

(A short and simple sentence, still using the 'do' word).

In your example, adding the word 'do' would sound more natural since there's an action actually done (compared to when the phrase is just used to show, 'expected to' or 'required to').